# Sidekiq won't execute job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, rails-activejob

This is my first time using sidekiq to perform scheduled actions within Rails 4. I created a perform method to find hashtaggable_ids that are empty and delete them from the database. I'm getting the error below when I attempt to run the job using the api for Rails Console.

remove_hashtag_orphans.rb

```
from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'>> RemoveHashtagOrphans.new.perform(hashtaggable_id)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `hashtaggable_id' for main:Object
```

The content of the jobs file is below.

```
 class RemoveHashtagOrphans < ActiveJob::Base
      queue_as :default

      def perform(hashtaggable_id)
        #Needs argument 
        orphans = SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.all.select {|h| h.hashtaggables.size == 0}
        orphans.map(&:destroy)
      end
    end

    RemoveHashtagOrphans.new.perform(hashtaggable_id)
```

The original method without sidekick is this.

```
def self.clean_orphans
  # Needs refactoring to call a single SQL query
  orphans = self.all.select { |h| h.hashtaggables.size == 0 }
  orphans.map(&:destroy)
end
```

Comment: with the code you're trying to run in rails console - the error is not actually coming from inside your method. You need to define `hashtaggable_id` before passing it as an argument.

Comment: What would be the best approach to converting the method at the bottom into a job? I have to find the hashtaggable_id's 1st, see which one has zero unique hashtags connected to them (hashtaggables), and then destroy all.

Comment: Well I'm not actually super experienced with Sidekiq (I've used Resque myself, not saying it's better though), but I think you have access to your DB connection and Rails app from inside the background job. So there should be no reason to refactor it other than wrapping it in a sidekiq method.

Comment: From what I can see, you need a argument for the perform method to work. I just can't fit this method into the context of the perform block.

Answer (score 0):

`RemoveHashtagOrphans.new.perform(hashtaggable_id)` will instantiate and execute the job right in process.  Use `RemoveHashtagOrphans.perform_later(hashtaggable_id)` to send the job to Sidekiq.

Your code failing because you have an undefined variable:

```
hashtaggable_id = 10
RemoveHashtagOrphans.new.perform(hashtaggable_id)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to test that it works with new.perform. Afterwards, I was going to use the perform_later method for production [RemoveHashtagOrphans.perform_at(1.month.from_now)]. It's just not working because hashtaggable_id is seen as a undefined method.

Comment: It's because that variable doesn't exist.  See update.

Comment: How would you pass all records from the simple_hashtag_hashtaggings table to the perform method. I don't necessarily want to search for a specific id, but find all. Does the perform method need a argument. Can I use def perform hashtags = SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.all? .... end If I can find all hashtaggable_ids in the table, and then perform the action. That would work.

Comment: I tried to use the method you created, but it doesn't work since hashtags.all.select is already a part of the method.

Comment: If you just want to run clean_orphans in the background with Sidekiq, call `Foo.delay.clean_orphans` instead of `Foo.clean_orphans`.

Comment: When I tried this in the console. I got  SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.delay.clean_orphans "8e3edab35a4c72071ec92ece" -- Inside of the Sidekiq terminal. It says 2016-04-26T20:03:00.463Z 10508 TID-n997c Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass JID-8e3edab35a4c72071ec92ece INFO: start
2016-04-26T20:03:00.656Z 10508 TID-n997c Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass JID-8e3edab35a4c72071ec92ece INFO: done: 0.193 sec
How would I add a monthly timer to it. perform_at(1.month.from.now). It 's not able to find perform_at when I access the method.

Comment: self.delay_for(1.month).clean_orphans

Comment: Alright, I placed the logic inside of the model file for the hashtag. Thank you for helping me.